# How to set up git policy so that files under a dir cannot be deleted?

Tags: git

In my git repo, I want to enforce a policy that files under a certain directory cannot be deleted.
I want to allow the following:

- creation of new files
- modification of existing files

Comment: Git itself doesn't do any permissions. If you want permissions in your git repository, you'll need to use a hosting solution that can enforce such permissions.

Comment: Use a pre-receive hook on your canonical repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The policy will need to be a server-side one:

- [pre-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks) if you have access/control of the Git remote repository hosting server
- GitHub Action (if the remote hosting service is GitHub.com), using [`tj-actions/changed-files`](https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files) on a protected branch (that you would update through a pull request): you can push any feature branch with any modification you want, but the Action will make sure the branch cannot be merged to a protected branch if files are deleted in a specific folder

```yaml
name: Check Deleted Files

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  check-deleted-files:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Get Changed Files
        id: changed-files
        uses: actions/changed-files@v1
      - name: Check Deleted Files
        run: |
          if echo "${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_modified_files }}" | grep -q "^folder-to-check/.*$"; then
            if ! echo "${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.deleted_files }}" | grep -q "^folder-to-check/.*$"; then
              echo "A file has been deleted in folder-to-check. Aborting commit."
              exit 1
            fi
          fi
```

A similar idea would apply to other hosting services like GitLab or Bitbucket.